# How to reference generated/aliased table in same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I want to find a user's position in a leaderboard and return the 4 users above and 4 users below their position.

My table, 'predictions', looks something like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+---------+
| id |  userId |  score |  rank |  gameId |
+----+---------+--------+-------+---------+
|  1 |      12 |     11 |     1 |      18 |
|  2 |       1 |      6 |     4 |      18 |
|  3 |      43 |      7 |     3 |      12 |
|  4 |       4 |      9 |     2 |      18 |
|  5 |      98 |      2 |     5 |      19 |
|  6 |       3 |      0 |     6 |      18 |
+----+---------+--------+-------+---------+
```

Obviously this isn't properly ordered, so I run this:

```
SELECT  l.userId,
        l.rank,
        l.score,
        l.createdAt,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    (SELECT * FROM `predictions` WHERE gameId = 18) l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

which gets me a nice table with each entry numbered.

I then want to search this generated table, find the row_number where userId = X, and then return the values 'around' that result.

I think I have the logic of the query down, I just can't work out how to reference the table 'generated' by the above query.

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT  l.userId,
        l.rank,
        l.score,
        l.createdAt,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    (SELECT * FROM `predictions` WHERE gameId = 18) l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
ORDER BY rank ASC) generated_ordered_table
WHERE row_number < (SELECT row_number FROM generated_ordered_table WHERE userId = 1)
ORDER BY row_number DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

This fails. What I'm trying to do is to generate my first table with the correct query, give it an alias of generated_ordered_table, and then reference this 'table' later on in this query.

How do I do this?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using

Comment: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev

Comment: Can you add your expected result please. AND a clarification about 4 below (is it any 4 or 4 closest or 4 furthest away) same for 4 above.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL version 8+ could have allowed the usage of [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), and [Common Table Expressions (CTEs)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html); which would have simplified the query quite a bit.

Now, in the older versions (your case), the "Generated Rank Table" ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)) cannot be referenced again in a subquery inside the `WHERE` clause. One way would be to do the same thing twice (`select` clause to get generated table) again inside the subquery, but that would be relatively inefficient.

So, another approach can be to use [Temporary Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html). We create a temp table first storing the ranks. And, then reference that temp table to get results accordingly:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gen_rank_tbl AS
(SELECT l.userId,
        l.rank,
        l.score,
        l.createdAt,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
 FROM   (SELECT * FROM `predictions` WHERE gameId = 18) l
 JOIN   (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
 ORDER BY rank ASC)
```

Now, you can reference this temp table to get the desired results:

```
SELECT *
FROM gen_rank_tbl 
WHERE row_number < (SELECT row_number FROM gen_rank_tbl WHERE userId = 1)
ORDER BY row_number DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bunch of unions

```
    select userid,rank,'eq' 
    from t where gameid = 18 and userid = 1
    union 
    (
    select userid,rank,'lt'
    from t
    where  gameid = 18 and rank  < (select rank from t t1 where t1.userid = 1 and t1.gameid = t.gameid)
    order by rank desc limit 4
    )
    union 
    (
    select userid,rank,'gt'
    from t
    where  gameid = 18 and rank  > (select rank from t t1 where t1.userid = 1 and t1.gameid = t.gameid)
    order by rank desc limit 4
    );

+--------+------+----+
| userid | rank | eq |
+--------+------+----+
|      1 |    4 | eq |
|      4 |    2 | lt |
|     12 |    1 | lt |
|      3 |    6 | gt |
+--------+------+----+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

But it's not pretty

Answer (score 0):

You can use two derived tables:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (@user_curRow = CASE WHEN user_id = @x THEN rn END) as user_rn
FROM (SELECT p.*, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS rn
      FROM (SELECT p.*
            FROM predictions p
            WHERE p.gameId = 18
            ORDER BY rank ASC
           ) p CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @curRow := 0, @user_curRow := -1) params
     ) p
HAVING rn BETWEEN @user_curRow - 4 AND @user_currow + 4;
```